# Maze Pattern Building in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, maze

Hello I am a newbie to python and using python 3.
I wish to learn patterns and printing e.g stars etc. I want to make maze pattern but i confused to make maze no 2-no4

```
No 1

    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
    @             @
    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
    @             @
    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
    @             @
    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @

No 2

    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @ @   @   @   @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @@@
    @ @ @ @ @ @   @
    @ @ @ @ @ @@@ @
    @ @ @ @ @     @
    @ @ @ @ @@@@@@@
    @ @ @ @       @
    @ @ @ @@@@@@@ @
    @ @ @         @
    @ @ @@@@@@@@@@@
    @ @           @
    @ @@@@@@@@@@@ @
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

No 3 

    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @ @           @
    @ @ @@@@@@@@@ @
    @ @ @       @ @
    @ @ @ @@@@@ @ @
    @ @ @ @   @ @ @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
    @ @ @ @@@ @ @ @
    @ @ @     @ @ @
    @ @ @@@@@@@ @ @
    @ @         @ @
    @ @@@@@@@@@@@ @
    @             @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

No 4 

    @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @ @           @
    @ @ @@@@@@@@@ @
    @ @ @       @ @
    @ @ @ @@@@@ @ @
    @ @ @ @   @ @ @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
    @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
    @ @ @   @ @ @ @
    @ @ @@@@@ @ @ @
    @ @       @ @ @
    @ @@@@@@@@@ @ @
    @           @ @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
```

This is my code maze no1:

```
def SimpleMaze(S):
    bool=1
    for i in range(S):
        if (i+1)%2==0:
            print('@'+' '*(S-2)+'@')
        else:
            if bool==1:
                print('@'+' '+'@'*(S-2))
            else:
                print('@'*(S-2)+' '+'@')
            bool=not bool
S= input("Nilai S:")
SimpleMaze(int(S))
```

Comment: What in particular is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am confused to make maze No 2 until No 4

Comment: @Nabunaga And what is the particular thing you're confused about? This seems like homework.

Comment: @Milk I've made maze no1 until no4, but I made no 2 to no4 using import turtle.I want to make no2 until no 4 does not use import turtle. I am confused to determine the location column and row. I don't know how to get to the expected result(number 2 until number 4) so looking for guidance on how to make code to get maze no 2 until no 4

Answer (score 1):

You built Maze 1 by assembling it row by row, but the other mazes appear to have messier patterns when you think about them in terms of rows.

Here's another way to break down the problem. Start with a solid block, with rows `0..R` and columns `0..C` (inclusive).

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Then envision yourself creating a maze by driving a bulldozer through it, opening up the path as you go. Under this approach, we can represent a maze as a set of driving instructions. For example, Maze 1 looks like this:

```
Start at r==-1, c==1.
Go South 2 steps.
Go East until c==C-1.
Go South 2 steps.
Go West until c==1.
Repeat ... until r>R.
```

I think Mazes 2 through 4 will be easier to think about in those terms. Ideally, each of those concepts (go south, go east, etc) could be implemented as simple functions or methods.